# Composition For WithOptions Pattern in Golang

Tags: go, design-patterns, composition, optional-parameters, variadic

In golang there's a pretty cool pattern for variadic options as

```golang
CallSomeStaff(mandatoryArg, WithSomeVariadicOption(val1), WithOtherVariadicOption(val2))
```

But what is the best/intended practice (or at least appropriate solution) once we want to extend the logic with any supper function which might add its own variadic options.

It seems tricky as

- The type of the options it self are not always exposed, just the Option Modifiers
- I'm not really sure, but it seams to me there. was a case when event a type of the Options Modifiers where privates instead just a final Modifier Function Values were exposed

So is it really possible to smoothly implement something like

```golang
func SupperWrapper(composedOptions ...SuperOrInheritedOptions) {
   superOptions := // filter for SuperOptions
   inheritedOptions := // filter for InheritedOptions

   doWhateverWith(superOptions)

   CallSomeWrappedStaff(...inheritedOptions)
}
```

The `interface{}` approach as an options type looks too spooky.

The most pretty stuff I can see that is possible to implement would look something like

```
SuperStaff(
  WithSupperOption1(), 
  WithSuperOption2(), 
  WithInheritedOptions(
    WithInheritedOption1(), 
    WithInheritedOption2(),
 ),
)
```

Any way is it possible really to end up with plain mix of options as

```golang
SuperStaff(
  WithSupperOption1(), 
  WithSuperOption2(), 
  WithInheritedOption1(), 
  WithInheritedOption2(),
)
```

And the Supper Question is what are really the option to go once the original types are not exposed for the options it self or even the modifiers types as well.

P.S. As I understand (as the simplest solution) a type composition like

```golang
type CompositeOptions = SuperOptions | InheritedOptions
```

is not supported in golang. Isn't it?

Thx

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to do with that `SupperWrapper` function. But I do discuss how to declare multiple option types and factory functions in [the talk I gave at GopherCon Europe 2023](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uM6z7RnReE&t=1349s). That might help.